# Very strange Find/Replace behaviour

Tags: vba, excel, replace, find

I have a Firebird database stored in Windows-1251 codepage and managed using IBExpert. I have to get some billing info using SQL, edit it and then send it to clients. I export query results into .csv (comma-separated values) format and then process a bunch of csvs into a pretty xls (with borders, fonts, etc.) using Microsoft Excel 2010. I have NO idea why, but IBExpert places a strange symbol everywhere in numeric values between decades (64 731 instead of 64731). `Asc()` method from VBA tells me that it's the #160 symbol in ASCII codepage.
NOW, the strangest observation I made: if you copy this symbol manually and delete it from everywhere using find/replace function of Excel, everything is OK. If you do the same thing in any text editor (e.g. good old notepad) everything is still OK. But when you try to automate the replacement using VBA, everything goes very, very wrong. No matter if you use a manually copied #160 from the csv itself or you generate it using `Chr(160)`, if you try to delete all those, VBA also deletes half of the commas. By comma I mean generally known symbol #44, you can google "ascii" pictures and check it out. I have to mark that again, the replacement affects *half* the commas, however all of them actually ARE the very same symbol, I rechecked that twice.
You can look for a link to a csv below, so you can reassure yourself with the fact that I'm not crazy.
Here is the code you can use to reproduce the magic

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=""
End Sub
```

I'll be very thankful to someone who will clarify this phenomenon, because I just can't believe that VBA is **that** buggy, I think I missed something somewhere

**UPDATE:** Guys, I am terribly sorry. I'm so dumb that I've uploaded the wrong csv. Here's the [right one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o48f7usgcerwtx0/%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BA.csv?dl=0)

Comment: @pnuts It is not shortened, the black button with "Скачать" caption is your choice

Comment: Your comment about a comma suggests to me that it is type-converting the replaced texts from Text to a Number which is then displayed as a number without commas. Comma is either a thousand seperator in some locales or a decimal seperator in others. For example, if i replace " " in "234 ,567", the result is then type converted to a number of 234567 (displayed per number formatting) whether I want to or not. To preserve type you will need to use a loop or something other than .Replace, or .replace number format to Text before you remove the character

Comment: An easy way to check what @Cor_Blimey says is to just replace with `" "` instead of `""`.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey Sorry, I just don't get your workaround ways, honestly. Please, clarify them or give some explaining code. How can a loop (with *what* inside?) work instead of a .Replace? Replacing #160 with text and then replacing text with nothing doesn't help too, do you mean something else? Explanation, I definitely need it.

Comment: I downloaded your linked file. It looks like a normal european CSV and opens fine in Excel 2010 (French version) apart from the text which is not in Cyrillic for me. I wonder if your problem is a misinterpretation of 160 as part of a Unicode sequence.

Comment: @grahamj42 Why should it NOT be a normal CSV? Why should it NOT open fine in Excel? Unicode is no-how involved here, wrong guess. I have a feeling that you completely misunderstood the problem. I want to get rid of #160 without damaging any other data inside CSV, and do it using VBA

Comment: No, I am trying to understand 1. How the #160 arrives in the string and 2. Why it's treated in a strange way. There is no #160 in the file you posted. Please can you edit the question to show the code you used to import the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've imported the CSV to Range("A1"). Here's what I've found:

- $F$2 = `4 708,200`
- That value is **not detected as a numeric**. This is due to the `CHR(160)` existing in the 2nd place (*the "space" after `4`*).
- If you want that value to become `4708200` (*four million...*), replace CHR(160) like you've done. This removes the comma **because now excel detects those values as numerics**.
- Since you haven't provided correct info, Excel thinks the comma is a **thousands separator**.

If it should rather be `4708,2` (*four thousand...*), correct it during your CSV import:

- To import the CSV correctly, you have to put CHR(160) as a thousands separator.
- The comma will act as a decimal sign.
- This way, Excel will interpret `4 708,200` as the numeric value `4708,2` during import.

When using `REPLACE` in VBA, Excel assumes the comma is a thousands separator. Why? Hard to say. However, you haven't provided that it's NOT. :)

Below is the code for importing the file correctly.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;H:\testfile2.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "testfile2.csv"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1251
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileThousandsSeparator = Chr(160) ' Here's that thousands separator!
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

**Update:** Here's the code that replaces your previous `Workbooks.OpenText` macro.

```
Sub eyecandy()
Dim SelectedItem
Dim Wb As Workbook, Sh As Worksheet
Dim WbName As String, WbFullName As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "  "
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "*.csv"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        If .Show = False Then Exit Sub

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each SelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            Set Wb = Workbooks.Add

            ' Get the file name
            WbFullName = Replace(SelectedItem, ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator, "")
            WbName = Replace(WbFullName, ".csv", "")

            ' Deletes unnecessary sheets
            Do Until Wb.Sheets.Count = 1
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Wb.Sheets(1).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Loop

            Set Sh = Wb.Sheets(1)

            With Sh.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                "TEXT;" & SelectedItem, Destination:=Sh.Range("$A$1"))
                .Name = WbName
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
                .TextFilePlatform = 1251
                .TextFileStartRow = 1
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                .TextFileThousandsSeparator = Chr(160)
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With
            Sh.Activate
            ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
            With Sh.UsedRange
                .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
                .Rows(1).Borders.Weight = xlThick
            End With
            Sh.Name = WbName
            Wb.SaveAs Filename:=WbName, FileFormat:=56
            Wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next SelectedItem
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Man, I am very sorry that I wasted your time writing all this code -_- I gave you the wrong file, re-check the question, please, I've edited it

Comment: Wow man, thanks much for the effort writing the solution! There is still one thing left to clarify, and it's **VERY IMPORTANT**. When I use `Workbooks.OpenText` to open the csv I **MUST** use the `Local:=True` option, otherwise all the contents will be scrambled during the export process, how do I do that with `QueryTables.Add` method? If it can help you somehow, here's the [full code](http://pastebin.com/wXCjEJyS)

Comment: I've included a new version of your `eyecandy` macro at the end of my answer. You won't need to use `Workbooks.OpenText`. Try my macro instead, I think it'll do what you requested.

Comment: I'm sorry about the maximalism. I simply recorded a macro for the `QueryTables.Add` lines. Feel free to remove all the lines you think are redundant. I am also a fan of minimalism. :)

Comment: I won't remove the tick from your answer but I have to put my own up because the method you suggest does not have the `Local` property enabling which is essential for me. I have to thank you again for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

So, as @takl suggested, the solution was to modify thousand separator property.
It's `.TextFileThousandsSeparator` if you are using `ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add` method and `.ThousandsSeparator` if you are using `Workbooks.OpenText` method.
I really appreciate his help, but I just *have* to use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method because it supports `Local` property. So, here's the edited file-processing loop from my script

```
'walk through selected files
For Each SelectedItem In .SelectedItems 
    Workbooks.OpenText _
        Filename:=SelectedItem, _
        Origin:=xlWindows, _
        StartRow:=1, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, _
        ThousandsSeparator:=Chr(160), _
        Local:=True
```